# Change all rules in iptables when changing IP address

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I have a network gateway system using iptables to allow/deny traffic to/from an internal network. I have to manually add and remove rules in `iptables` depending on the requirements of the entities in the internal network, including NATing their traffic. Trusted entities on the internal network can request rules to be added and removed as required. The end result is a bunch of rules in the `nat` and `filter` tables, including `POSTROUTING` rules with `SNAT` targets, setting the source IP to that of the gateway system, and rules in other tables with the gateway external ip address as `dst`.

*I want to be able to set the IP of the gateway system on the fly*. This would of course have disruptive consequences to TCP sessions etc., but let's keep that out of the picture. The system handles these issues with other mechanisms.

The problem is that an unknown number of rules in the firewall tables still refer to this old source IP address.

**Is there a way to easily change all these rules to use the new IP address instead of the old one?** Of course I can also accept some fancy script using sed/awk or similar if you are more of a bash wizard than me...

Comment: Probably you should just write a script which flush the tables and add all the rules again with desired IP(s).

Comment: @TomYan This works for the "remove old rules" part, but requires me to signal all the entities in the network and then they need to retransmit their required rules. Or I can make smarter software that remembers all rules separately and does some magic to set them again with a different IP. But this is besides the question :) Thanks though.

Comment: You need to supply more information about your network setup, "entities" etc. This doesn't seem like a simple sed/awk question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the traffic being SNATed always uses the outbound interface's IP address, replace `-j SNAT` with `-j MASQUERADE`. This will use the same conntrack-based SNAT but will select the replacement source address automatically.

You can mass-edit iptables rules using `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore`:

- For example, to edit the ruleset interactively (especially if your editor has a good search-and-replace function):

  ```
  iptables-save > /tmp/rules
  vim /tmp/rules
  iptables-restore < /tmp/rules
  ```

  Using 'vipe' from moreutils:

  ```
  iptables-save | vipe | iptables-restore
  ```
- To mass-replace one exact IP address with another (keeping in mind that `.` is a wildcard character in regexes, as well as using `\b` to ensure that "12.34" will not accidentally match "112.34"):

  ```
  iptables-save | sed 's/\b12\.34\.56\.78\b/12.34.56.99/g' | iptables-restore
  ```

But in my opinion, *any* editing of iptables rules (including script-based "iptables -A" setup) is a bad approach. Instead, keep an `iptables.rules` *file* (in the iptables-save format) as the "source" and always load the ruleset from that file. Then, you can start using some form of macro/templating language to define the IP address once and refer to it everywhere – similar to how it's done when deploying configuration files through Salt/Ansible (if anybody still uses those).

- For example (don't actually do this; it'll spiral into something unmanageable too quickly):

  ```
  cat /etc/iptables.rules | sed 's/%CUST_IP%/12.34.56.78/g' | iptables-restore
  ```
- I would also suggest taking a look at Ferm, which implements an alternative syntax for iptables rules – a bit more readable in general, but also has macros built in so you can `@def $cust_ip` once and refer to it everywhere.

  ```
  domain (ip ip6) {
      @def dns_host4 = 10.10.0.53;
      @def ntp_host4 = 10.10.0.123;

      table filter {
          chain FORWARD {
              daddr ($dns_host4 $ntp_host4) accept;
          }
      }

      table nat {
          chain PREROUTING {
              proto (tcp udp) dport 53 DNAT to-destination $dns_host4;
              proto udp dport 123 DNAT to-destination $ntp_host4;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  This works similarly to the iptables-restore – instead of making changes live, you edit `/etc/ferm.conf` and run `ferm` to reload the whole ruleset when done. If an IP address changes, just edit the @def macro in ferm.conf and reload.

  (Also, it's good to get used to this if you eventually end up switching to nftables, as it works pretty much the same as Ferm – of course the syntax is a bit different, but it also has $macros and you edit /etc/nftables.conf and reload the whole thing at once.)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest iptables in combination with ipset.

In iptables you would have your rule but then add --match-set setname src

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -s whatever ... --match-set setname src
iptables -I PREROUTING -s whatever ... --match-set setname dst
```

Then to disable the rule you would remove the ip address from the set named "setname"
To enable it you just add an ip address to setname.

Then iptables remain the same and your just adding and subtracting entries from setname

Each rule would have a different name as needed.